# Is it possible to install Conda packages in AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, netcdf4

I’m using AWS Glue Jobs with the PythonShell mode for processing some NetCDF4 files. I need to perform some analytics on the data using the scitools-iris package.
On my local Ubuntu machine, I’ve successfully installed it using conda-forge. I tried searching the documentation on how to install the iris package using conda on AWS Glue. But I can’t find anything.

Do you recommend using a different compute option for this problem?

Comment: No conda installs with Glue.  I think you'll need to find or build a whl file